# overediting a post

Tags: discussion, editing

What should we do if somebody over-edits our post?

e.g, my original post was not perfect, and I appreciate some of what was added, but the edit changed my position on the subject, made the question "not a question" and left my name attached to the post:

[Will setting a cron job to delete ._ shadow files on a linux share work?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/60958/help-me-understand-the-shadow-files-for-every-mac-file-that-gets-sent-to-a-li)

Can I see my original post to compare?  Is there a "revert" or something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Roll it back and add a comment as to why you prefer your wording or better, make a second edit to keep the good and further refine things you feel could be made better.

In your specific case, I edited it quite severely since it was a rant and they get flagged and closed more often than not, but as the author of the post you generally get extra leeway in how a post reads. Who cares if people are livid - the emotional state of others on a chat board or even one person's frustration rarely add value to a question on the site so we do edit out rants as a point of policy. I did leave in the "livid" part to indicate that you were frustrated and chose those words to characterize this function and your view of it.

Since the site is [edited collaboratively](https://apple.stackexchange.com/faq#editing) - you should expect a back and forth as well as be open to what the regulars consider "good form" when you are new to a particular site.

Just click on the edited... link to see revisions and comments as to why a particular edit was made...

[image]

Do let the [faq](https://apple.stackexchange.com/faq#editing) soak in on the part about being comfortable with others editing your words.

Comment: I won't revert, I know it was done in the right spirit...  which is why I ask.  I was surprised at the heavy edit.  Note that the edit contains an *answer* to my question... "should I set up a cron job?", but I'm still not sure if that *was* the right thing to do in this case.  I'm not new to Stackexchange, only new to the Apple forum.  I haven't seen this kind of edit before.

Comment: I'm glad you're here and also glad for the content. It was on the heavy end of edits for sure but we get hundreds of "apple sucks - why did they do this stupid thing" and I honestly didn't want your name colored into that category. It's a great question. I did take a second edit at your title - I hope the last edit captures your main intent better.